# Django - getting a list of foreign key (related) objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

Having a model:

```
class Combination(models.Model):
    changed_by = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='combinations')
```

how do I get a list/queryset of all users, that created such a Combination?

Answer (score 3):

`user_instance.combinations.all()` should get you the combinations of the user in question.

---

If, however, you want to select all users that have created at least one `Combination` instance, then you have some options:

1. Simply use `User.objects.filter(combination__isnull=False)` like user @PauloAlmeida pointed out in the comments of this answer (I did not know this way even though it is right there in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships), so I also learned something new today).
2. You could use a less efficient but simpler python code to iterate over users:

   ```
   user_list = []
   for u in User.objects.all():
       if u.combinations.exists():
           # add users that have at least one combination
           user_list.append(u)
   ```
3. You could use a less efficient but simpler python code to iterate over combinations:

   ```
   user_set = set()
   for c in Combination.objects.filter(changed_by__isnull=False):
       # will have no effect if user is already present in user_set
       user_set.add(c.changed_by)
   ```

Comment: the question is to get all users that created a "Combination".

Comment: Do you mean: select all users that have created at least one Combination instance?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want

Comment: @altipard I think you want `User.objects.filter(combination__isnull=False)`.

Comment: For the clarified requirement, @PauloAlmeida's comment is better than any of the listed 3 alternatives.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper : you are right and I updated my answer. I learned something new today.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida : you are right and I updated my answer. I learned something new today.